# How do I resolve this error? "'function' object has no attribute 'StandardScaler'"

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, jupyter, data-preprocessing

```
def preprocessing(df:pd.DataFrame,scaler:str):
  standard_scaler= preprocessing.StandardScaler()
  not_uv=[]
  for column in df.columns:
    if column != 'uv': # uv is target
      not_uv.append(column)
  if scaler == 'standard':
    standard_df = pd.DataFrame(standard_scaler.fit_transfrom(df[not_uv]), columns = not_uv)
    standard_df = pd.concat([standard_df,df[['uv']]],axis=1)
    return standard_df
```

```
preprocessing(df_13,'standard')
```

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'StandardScaler'
```

i want to make preprocssing function
whats wrong with my code?

Comment: You have defined ```preprocessing``` as a function.  i.e. ```def preprocessing(...)```.  But now in the next line, you're calling ```standard_scaler= preprocessing.StandardScaler()```.  Perhaps rename your ```preprocessing``` function something else?

Answer (score 1):

This code generates a conflict between user-defined function **preprocessing** and sklearn built-in function **preprocessing**. Simply import and make instance like this.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

standard_scaler= StandardScaler()
```

**OR**

Change your function name **preprocessing** to **preprocessings** or something else. Never declare or make an instance of built-in keywords.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the function `def preprocessing(...):` is same as `preprocessing.StandardScaler()`. Which means you are overwriting the memory. Change the name of the function. For Example:

```
def new_preprocessing(df:pd.DataFrame,scaler:str):
  standard_scaler= preprocessing.StandardScaler()
  not_uv=[]
  for column in df.columns:
    if column != 'uv': # uv is target
      not_uv.append(column)
  if scaler == 'standard':
    standard_df = pd.DataFrame(standard_scaler.fit_transfrom(df[not_uv]), columns = not_uv)
    standard_df = pd.concat([standard_df,df[['uv']]],axis=1)
    return standard_df
```